# Back to back CGAffineTransformScale animations cause view to become too big

Tags: swift

Quickly animating between `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)` and `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.2, y: 0.2)` causes the view to become bigger than expected.

Why is that?

[image: Screen recording of the issue]

Example Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let greenView = UIView()
    var isTransformed = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        view.addSubview(greenView)
        greenView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX-50, y: 150, width: 100, height: 100)
        greenView.backgroundColor = .green
        
        let transformButton = UIButton()
        transformButton.setTitle("Transform", for: .normal)
        transformButton.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX-50, y: 275, width: 100, height: 40)
        transformButton.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
        transformButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapTransform), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(transformButton)
    }
    
    @objc func didTapTransform() {
        if isTransformed {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
                var t = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                self.greenView.transform = t
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
                var t = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.2, y: 0.2)
                self.greenView.transform = t
            }
        }
        print(greenView.transform)
        isTransformed = !isTransformed
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add the `.beginFromCurrentState` option to the animations?

Comment: @HangarRash still repros :/

Comment: are u pressing the button quickly (quickly means within, 2 seconds before one animation finishes) ? if so the second animation will not start from the expected state. then it will behave like this.

Comment: Yes button is getting pressed multiple times per second. Any idea why it behaves like this? Changing the animation to a rotation does not over-rotate.

Answer (score 0):

you have to avoid it going to continue another animation before your first animation complete. put a global variable to detect is one animation is ongoing or not like this..

```
 import UIKit
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
        let greenView = UIView()
        var isTransformed = false
        var isOneAnimationOngoing = false
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            view.backgroundColor = .white
            
            view.addSubview(greenView)
            greenView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX-50, y: 150, width: 100, height: 100)
            greenView.backgroundColor = .green
            
            let transformButton = UIButton()
            transformButton.setTitle("Transform", for: .normal)
            transformButton.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX-50, y: 275, width: 100, height: 40)
            transformButton.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
            transformButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapTransform), for: .touchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(transformButton)
        }
        
        @objc func didTapTransform() {
        if !isOneAnimationOngoing {
            isOneAnimationOngoing = true
            
            if isTransformed {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.00, animations: { () -> Void in
                    var t = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                    self.greenView.transform = t
                    
                }) { completed in
                    self.isOneAnimationOngoing = false
                }
                
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.00, animations: { () -> Void in
                    var t = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.2, y: 0.2)
                    self.greenView.transform = t
                    
                }) { completed in
                    self.isOneAnimationOngoing = false
                }
            }
            
            isTransformed = !isTransformed
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: For good UX, I want the next animation to start immediately, and have the view animate back to the scale=1 transform